# "Segmentation Fault [Core Dumped]" while initializing 2d array of char dynamically

Tags: c++

I want to get an array of strings from user. I am getting the exception "Segmentation Fault [Core Dumped]" on runtime.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long testCaseCount = 0;
    cin >> testCaseCount;
    char **testCases;
    *testCases = new char[testCaseCount];
    for(int i=0;i<testCaseCount;i++) {
        cin >> testCases[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: you are initializing one dimension but you are not initializing the other...

Comment: Were you planning on allocating space for those strings you're reading in? While pondering that, just ditch the idea entirely and use `std::vector<std::string>`. And check the results of your IO operations; *please*.

Comment: I want the size of string to be dynamic, so how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your sugessions std:string, but can't it be done with char, I will be more interested in knowing how to do this way.

Comment: If you want to write C code in a C++ world, sure. Some very smart people designed some *very* smart classes to make this both easier and *consistent*. I sincerely advise you exploit that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is material for a chat room or discussion forum.

Answer (score 3):

You're not allocating space for each string being read. The following are two ways to do what you're trying, the first being the mostly-C approach you seem to want to take, the second fully exploiting the standard library for all its glory.

Both of the following examples should result in the same test strings given the same input content. The first resizes with each new additional char arrival. Though it may seem overkill, it is actually *simpler* than maintaining a geometric growth algorithm.

That said, here is the code. I leave it to you to decide which of these is more prone to errors and bugs (and I just wrote both online, so there are bound to be bugs regardless).

**The Hard Way**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    unsigned int testCaseCount = 0;
    char **testCases = NULL;

    // read and validate we received a count greater than zero
    if (cin >> testCaseCount && testCaseCount > 0)
    {
        // allocate + nullinitialize that many pointers
        testCases = new char *[testCaseCount]();
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < testCaseCount && cin; ++i)
        {
            // skip leading whitespace
            char ch;
            while (cin.get(ch) && std::isspace(ch));
            if (cin)
            {
                // read chars until whitespace or EOF. vsize
                //  represents the size of the allocated buffer
                char *value = new char[1]();
                size_t vsize = 1;
                while (cin.get(ch) && !std::isspace(ch))
                {
                    // allocate larger buffer
                    char *tmp = new char[vsize + 1];

                    // copy in old content to new buffer
                    std::copy(value, value + vsize, tmp);
                    std::swap(value, tmp);

                    // save new char and terminator
                    value[vsize - 1] = ch;
                    value[vsize++] = 0;

                    // delete old buffer
                    delete[] tmp;
                }

                // save accumulated value.
                testCases[i] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    // show test cases
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < testCaseCount && testCases[i]; ++i)
        std::cout << testCases[i] << '\n';

    // cleanup
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < testCaseCount && testCases[i]; ++i)
        delete[] testCases[i];
    delete[] testCases;

    return 0;
}
```

---

**The Easy Way**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    unsigned int testCaseCount = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> testCases;

    if (cin >> testCaseCount)
    {
        std::string s;
        while (testCaseCount-- && cin >> s)
            testCases.emplace_back(s);
    }

    // show test cases
    for (auto const& s : testCases)
        std::cout << s << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you `return 0`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Habit. would you prefer I returned `EXIT_SUCCESS` ?

Comment: I'd prefer you omitted the entirely redundant statement entirely!

Answer (score 2):

You have to write at least as

```
char **testCases = new char *;
*testCases = new char[testCaseCount];
```

Though it is not clear why you do not want to write simply as

```
char *testCases = new char[testCaseCount];
```

And do not forget to delete what was allocated with the operator new.

Take into account that it is not "an array of strings". It is simply an array of characters. If you want to get an array of strings you should at first decide what will be the maximum length of a string.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to allocate space for the pointers to the first character of each string:

```
char** testCases = new char*[testCaseCount];
```

Then you'll need to allocate space for each string:

```
testCaseCount[i] = new char[maxStringLength];
cin >> testCaseCount[i];
```

However, this is dangerous-- cin won't do any bounds checking. You really should use std::string.

Answer (score 0):

> Getting Exception "Segmentation Fault [Core Dumped]" on runtime.

You have undefined behavior by dereferencing an undefined pointer in:

```
*testCases = new char[testCaseCount];
```

---

> Objective: I want to get an array of strings from user

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you use an [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    long testCaseCount = 0;
    std::cin >> testCaseCount;
    std::vector<std::string> testCases(testCaseCount);
    for (auto& s : testCases)
        std::cin >> s;
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b167d64601a8b817)